# such + noun phrase + that

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Consider these two examples:

- My secretary is such an honest woman that she never says anything about my business.
- My secretary is **of** such honesty that she never says a word about my business.

Why is 'such' in the second example preceded by the preposition 'of' and not in the first sentence?

Comment: Because "such" can be used in different ways.http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/such?q=such

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be a fairly deep question, and I think the answer has to do with the methods English has to describe things and the differing syntactic roles that English allows for its parts of speech.  I can think of the following ways to describe an honest person.

1. By *direct modification*.  English usually puts the modifier before the noun (as you have in "honest woman").  So you may say

> My *honest* secretary is so much so that she never says anything about
>   my business.

2. By *complementary adjective*.  That is, by placing the modifier after a **copulative verb**

> My secretary **is** so *honest* that she never says anything about my
>   business.

3. By *nominative complement*, by placing an equivalent noun after a **copulative verb**.  This is the same structure as the complementary adjective, but with a noun instead of an adjective:

> My secretary **is** such an *honest woman* that she never says anything about my business.

4. By action, i.e., by having the person take the characteristic as a *direct object* of a **transitive verb**:

> My secretary **possesses** such *honesty* that she never says anything
>   about my business.

5. By modifying the person's actions, which will require an *adverb* or *adverbial phrase* modifying the **verb** associated with the action.

> My secretary **operates** so *honestly* that she never says anything about my business.

So let's get to your questions.  Why no *of* in the first formulation?  *Of* is a preposition, and as such requires an object to complete its sense.  That object must be a noun, and your chosen word is *honest*, an adjective.  With an adjective, you have to choose either 1 (the direct modification) or 2 (the complementary adjective).

Why is there an *of* in the second formulation?   Your chosen word is now *honesty*, a noun and you must use the syntax that accommodates a noun.  But the choices for a noun don't work. You can't use 3 (nominative complement) because your secretary isn't a quality (honesty); she's a person.  You can't use 4 (direct object) because you've chosen *is*, which is not a transitive verb.

But what you can do is choose 5 (adverbial phrase) by using a prepositional phrase with *of* to describe the manner of how your secretary is.  The preposition requires a noun as its object, and you have just such a word, *honesty* available.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible expressions with "such" is

- My secretary is a woman of such honesty + that-clause

and you can shorten such a sentence to

- My secretary is of such honesty + that-clause